# QGIS 3.10 problem with uploading Geopackage uploaded vector layers shown displaced

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, layers, geopackage

I am trying to upload a Geopackage file containing various vector layers into my project (currently using QGIS 3.10). Uploaded layers are shown as if they were displaced on the base map of Google Satellite. I tried to adapt the CRS of the project to the CRS of the imported layers but the result is the same.
Even stranger is that I have shared the same gpkg with another QGIS user and he had no problem uploading it in the right place (don't know which version he is using).
Does anybody know what is happening?

[image: Here is a screenshot of the problem]

Comment: Is EPSG:5382 the CRS of the layers? It seems like a datum transformation, from its base CRS (SIRGAS-ROU98 to WGS84). Can you include in the question the output of `$ projinfo -s EPSG:5381 -t EPSG:4326 -k operation -o PROJ`?

Comment: Layers were created in Global Mapper and then exported as a Geopackage. CRS of the layers is EPSG: 31981. 
Where can I run that command in QGIS?

Comment: EPSG:31981 is based on SIRGAS 2000 base CRS, so `$ projinfo -s EPSG:4674 -t EPSG:4326 -k operation -o PROJ` might be useful too. Run _projinfo_ commands at a terminal emulator. _$_ stands for a normal user prompt.

Comment: Command: $ projinfo -s EPSG:4674 -t EPSG:4326 -k operation -o PROJ
Output from terminal:
Operation No. 1:

EPSG:15894, SIRGAS 2000 to WGS 84 (1), 1.0 m, Latin America - SIRGAS 2000 by country

PROJ string:
+proj=noop

Comment: Command: $ projinfo -s EPSG:5381 -t EPSG:4326 -k operation -o PROJ
Output:Operation No. 1:

EPSG:5384, SIRGAS-ROU98 to WGS 84 (1), 1.0 m, Uruguay

PROJ string:
+proj=noop

Comment: Please, edit the question to include the information. But it seems to not be a datum transformation problem. Please also include a screenshot of the Transformations tab of the project properties. If those same transformations are configured for the project, it's probably not a problem with the version of QGIS or the transformations used, but some procedural difference. In that case you would have to detail your procedure in a way that is reproducible. Probably attach test data.